# MySQL and importing decimals from CSV

Tags: mysql

I'm messing around with MySQL, using the Workbench to import a CSV of building permits in the city.  Two of the columns are latitude and longitude, and because these are relatively precise locations, keeping the decimals is pretty important, there are maximum 6 decimals after many of these entries.  For example, the latitude and longitude columns might say 35.678121, -21.57890

I generated a database using LOAD DATA INFILE, and got all my data in.  I had set the Latitude and Longitude columns as Decimal(6,6), but when all the data was imported in, all of the values in my table say 0.999999 and -0.999999.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have set up the decimal columns incorrectly. The first digit represents the total number of digits that will be stored. The second digit represents the number of decimal places. By declaring decimal(6,6), you are saying store only six digits total and six of those are to the right of the decimal point. Increase to decimal(9,6) and you will have the space to store the whole number.

Comment: This makes so much more sense...  I misread the initial glance over the decimal type.  Thank you

Comment: Easy mistake to make. I've done it numerous times myself.

Comment: Food for thought if you want to get into more complex geo-spatial operations with your data: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html